# Bootstrap MultiSelect DropDown with MVC and Ajax serialize in partial view

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, view

I have a problem in posting data from my partial view to controller: in few words controller action is not executed.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class BloccoQuartiVM: MessaggioVM
{
    public int IdAttivita { get; set; }
    public IList<int> IdPersona { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Persona> ElencoPersone { get; set; }
}
```

`Persona` class have `int Id` and `string Name`

and this my partial view

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator" id="frmBloccoQuarti" name="frmBloccoQuarti">
    <div>
        <div class="cell padding10 size3">
            <label for="IdAttivita">Attivita</label>
            <input type="number" id="IdAttivita" name="IdAttivita" value="@Model.IdAttivita" />
            <br />
            <label for="IdPersona">Persona</label>
            <select id="IdPersona" name="IdPersona" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
                @if (Model.ElencoPersone != null)
                {
                    foreach (Persona persona in Model.ElencoPersone)
                    {           
                        <option value="@persona.Id">@persona.NomePersona</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

    <div class="cell padding10 size1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="BloccaQuarti" class="imgBottone imgBlocca btn btn-primary" id="bloccaQuarti" form="frmBloccoQuarti" />          
        </div>    
    </div>
```

this is the ajax call to post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bloccaQuarti").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("BloccaQuarti", "Blocchi")",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#frmBloccoQuarti").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#bloccoQuarti").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("errore: ");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the action in Controller `BlocchiController`

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult BloccaQuarti(BloccoQuartiVM arguments)
{
    // do something with arguments
}
```

when i click on `BloccaQuarti` button this action is not called

if i remove the multiselect all works fine, so think the problem is in it

debugging javascript i see that `Persona` selected item are (correctly?) written in this way: `IdPersona=1&IdPersona=2...`

i try to change in my Model `public IList<int> IdPersona { get; set; }` with `array`, `IEnumerable`, `List`, even swithcing type to string but nothing change

Comment: You seem to have a submit button which is called "bloccaQuarti" which will submit your form to "Blocchi/SaveResults"... but you are binding an ajax post on the click event as well?

Comment: sorry, was a mistake of a test i make, i will fix message. the only action i call is BloccaQuarti via Ajax

Comment: Ok..You will also need to change the type of the button to "button".. not "submit"

Comment: You are using MVC, why not just use the built in helper methods? @Html.BeginForm() see documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Master Yoda, i don't like very much helper, prefer old plain html tag

Comment: @Wheels73, type="Button" was the solution, with type ="Submit" it's value was post back and so no Action with such parameters was found. If you make an answer with this i will mark it as accepted one

Comment: @gt.guybrush - morning.. Glad to hear you've got it working. And thanks.. I'll post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, change the type of your button to Type="button" instead of submit. That can then trigger the ajax post on the intended click event.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JQuery serialize method returns an encoded string (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/))

You could use the `serializeObject` method instead from [the David G. Hong's plugin](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject) (see [documentation](https://plugins.jquery.com/serializeObject/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bloccaQuarti").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("BloccaQuarti", "Blocchi")",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#frmBloccoQuarti").serializeObject(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#bloccoQuarti").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("errore: ");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or you can build your javascript object before the ajax call :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#bloccaQuarti").click(function () {
    var data = {
        IdAttivita : $('#IdAttivita').val(),
        IdPersona : $('#IdPersona').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("BloccaQuarti", "Blocchi")",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#bloccoQuarti").html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("errore: ");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: SerializeObject is not a native JQuery function and requires a plug-in. OP can not get his action to be hit.... he's not having a problem serializing the form.

Comment: serializeObject  look interesting but seem that converts all values to string

Comment: just converted my model to all string properties (and string[] for seleced values) but still only works if i select nothing in dropdow

Comment: ASP.NET will automatically convert the string to int if the name are the same

Answer (score 1):

As per your functionality, you don't need of to pass the model.

> As you have one textbox and one dropdown control inside your partial
> view, you can simply pass three strings - the "textbox value", the
> "dropdown value" and the "dropdown text".
>
> **That's it. Why do you need to pass the complex model, if it can be achieved in simple way ?**

Even if it is possible to pass the complex model, but you don't need here.

So, you can modify your Action like below

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult BloccaQuarti(string textvalue, string optionvalue, string optiontext)
{
    // do something with arguments
}
```

And the ajax call would be like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#bloccaQuarti").click(function () {
    var textvalue =  $('#IdAttivita').val();
    var optionvalue = $("#IdPersona option:selected").val();
    var optiontext = $("#IdPersona option:selected").text();
    
    $.ajax({
       url: "@Url.Action("BloccaQuarti", "Blocchi")",
       type: "POST",
       data: {"textvalue": textvalue, "optionvalue": optionvalue,"optiontext": optiontext},
       success: function (result) {
            $("#bloccoQuarti").html(result);
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("errore : " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i have many more fields, omitted here to mantain question readable, this is why i prefer to send form instead of  every single fields

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are not recogniszed as BloccoQuartiVM elements.
Try to send them as string and then manipulate.

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult BloccaQuarti(string arguments)
{
    // do something with arguments
}
```